# Localization Android Arabic below android N

Tags: android, localization, arabic-support

Hey guys i am working on application that support both English and Arabic, the English version is working fine but the Arabic do not working right below Android N

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, check your device supports Arabic language.

Secondly, make sure that the following methods are used to change the language on Android at runtime for different API's:

`updateConfiguration` for API < 17

`createConfigurationContext` for API ≥ 17

For more information, please check the following article: [change-language-programmatically-at-runtime](https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758)

Comment: i followed this tutorial but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to update configuration in resources as well on lower API. Try this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar");

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
} else {
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    Locale.setDefault(config.locale);
    Resources resources = applicationContext.getResources();
    resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```